Macbook keeps restarting when in sleep mode
When I leave my macbook pro 2019 16-inch in sleep mode for a period of time it restarts without any interaction with the computer. I hear the startup noise when I'm away from the computer. It has been doing this consistently for the last month.
Here is the error message -
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80039946fe): Wake transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering fullwake from darkwake. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x79.
Backtracing specified thread
Panicked task 0xffffff8b5c0e9dd8: 330 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 6), panicked thread: 0xffffff94f46600c8, Frame : Return Address
0xfffffffdef003790 : 0xffffff8003375777 
0xfffffffdee3b3930 : 0xffffff8003254936 
0xfffffffdee3b39c0 : 0xffffff8003252a30 
0xfffffffdee3b3a10 : 0xffffff80033726a0 
0xfffffffdee3b3a50 : 0xffffff8003371e8b 
0xfffffffdee3b3a90 : 0xffffff7f98442fd5 
0xfffffffdee3b3ac0 : 0xffffff7f9845cf29 
0xfffffffdee3b3ad0 : 0xffffff7f984461b0 
0xfffffffdee3b3b60 : 0xffffff7f9844be3e 
0xfffffffdee3b3c00 : 0xffffff80038dca46 
0xfffffffdee3b3c70 : 0xffffff80039029f5 
0xfffffffdee3b3cc0 : 0xffffff80038dd269 
0xfffffffdee3b3d10 : 0xffffff8003902849 
0xfffffffdee3b3d90 : 0xffffff800399fb31 
0xfffffffdee3b3de0 : 0xffffff80038f5f9d 
0xfffffffdee3b3e40 : 0xffffff80038f340f 
0xfffffffdee3b3e90 : 0xffffff80038f0b32 
0xfffffffdee3b3ee0 : 0xffffff80038f09cb 
0xfffffffdee3b3f20 : 0xffffff800390f1fe 
0xfffffffdee3b3f60 : 0xffffff800390e826 
0xfffffffdee3b3fa0 : 0xffffff80031c019e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(598.0)[79F2F7E4-E451-35E1-BF22-1EFFA4192888]@0xffffff7f98439000->0xffffff7f98467fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[250D1260-447B-3BF3-96B2-C784699ED806]@0xffffff8005568000->0xffffff8005599fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff94f46600c8): kernel_task

Mac OS version:
23G93

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Mon Jul 29 21:13:00 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B8A95C25-3789-30A2-AE3C-7A48E0B91426
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000002e00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8003000000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000002ee4000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff80030e4000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002f00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4693361791757
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000444c2299760
  Sleep   : 0x0000041853af90a8 0x00000987d356fb00 0x0000040c5384a8cb
  Wake    : 0x000004188849f9ab 0x000009a6b5dd7a26 0x000004186730c144
Compressor Info: 4% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 7% of segments limit (OK) with 2 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff80279a9000 - 0xffffffa0279a9000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff80279a9000 - 0xffffff80299aa000
  . VM    : 0xffffff80299aa000 - 0xffffff84f61a9000
  . RO    : 0xffffff84f61a9000 - 0xffffff868f9a9000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff868f9a9000 - 0xffffff8b5c1a9000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8b5c1a9000 - 0xffffff90289a9000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff90289a9000 - 0xffffff94f51a9000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff94f51a9000 - 0xffffff99c19a9000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff99c19a9000 - 0xffffffa0279a9000
  Metadata: 0xffffffb07cb62000 - 0xffffffb09cb62000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffb09cb62000 - 0xffffffb09fb62000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

last started kext at 44898224785: >AudioAUUC    1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f981a3000, size 12288)
last stopped kext at 4648443193533: >!ABacklight    180.9 (addr 0xffffff7f97805000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    7440.8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   135
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    5.0.5
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.11
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   5.0.5
>!AGFXHDA   340.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    440.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 8.1.9
>!A!IKBLGraphics    22.0.5
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   8.1.9
>!AMuxControl2  8.1.9
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AUIO  1
>!ASunrise  1
>!AHV   1
>AGDCBacklightControl   8.1.9
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>BridgeAudioCommunication   440.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 22.0.5
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.17
|SCSITaskUserClient 495
>!UMass!SInterfaceNub   556
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   650.140.2
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   2236.141.1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    405
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ADiskImages2  276.120.7
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>!AHIDKeyboard  7440.3
>!AActuatorDriver   7440.9
>!AMultitouchDriver 7440.9
>!AInputDeviceSupport   7440.1
>!AHS!BDriver   7440.8
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   340.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  5.0.5
|IOAudio!F  540.3
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  8.1.9
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IOAVB!F    1220.1
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1240.15
@!AGPUWrangler  8.1.9
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 5.0.5
@kext.AMDSupport    5.0.5
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   481.40.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    8.1.9
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  598
|IOGraphics!F   598
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  352.50.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  11.6.1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1240.15
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ALockdownMode 1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  556
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  245
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  495
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  495
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
|IO!S!F 2.1
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   6.3.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.XrtHostedXnu   1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.Compression    1.0
@kec.corecrypto 14.0


That panic log says your graphics drivers are causing a kernel panic when entering fullwake from darkwake. Darkwake is another name for "powernap". Anyway, it's not normal. Run Apple Hardware Diagnostics. Was it connected to an external display or eGPU? Do you have DisplayLink (note: not DisplayPort) drivers installed?

Thanks for your help @Spiff. I ran apple diagnostics, nothing was found. I do have an external display. The power to the mac is coming from the dell screen through a USBC cable. It's been used this way for years but the last month it's getting this issue constantly

Can you provide the exact model number of the display? I want to see what it's doing over that USB-C cable. Did you have to install drivers on your Mac to get it to talk to the display?

Ok sure, it's a Dell U3818DW, and nope I didn't install drivers.

Okay it seems like it's just using USB's DP alt mode, which is a very clean way of doing things; nothing sketchy. It would still be interesting to know if the same problem happens if you don't leave the MBP hooked up to an external display. This is just for narrowing down what triggers the panic, in case it gives clues for how to fix it or at least work around it.

To narrow it down a bit more. If I take the usb-c cable out it doesn't have the issue and also if I plug the original power chord plus the usb-c cable it doesn't have the issue. I never had this issue in the past though so wondering, is the cable the problem or an OS issue?

Well the OS shouldn't panic regardless. BTW do you have anything else on USB, possibly via the display's other USB ports? If so, try disconnecting any other USB devices from the display but leave the display itself connected, and see if that makes a difference.
